# Date format exception

Tags: vba, parsing, date, format

I'm parsing date from text box to variable(dt) but it's showing "02/14/2014" where as txtxDate.text contains 14/02/2014.

Below is the code, pleas suggest if I'm doing something wrong.

```
Dim dt As Date
dt = Date.Parse(txtDate.Text)
```

but above code was not working and giving an error can not convert to date

Then I've used

```
Date.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing, system.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dt)
```

but with in this variable(dt) is showing time #12:00:00 AM#

please help....

Comment: i think your system date format may be MM/dd/yyyy - What result you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes Sathish, it was but now it's dd/MM/yyyy

Even after changing it to dd/MM/yyyy it's showing same. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine now, I've changed Sql server language to British English